# Angular Directive Karma Jasmine Testing with dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, d3.js, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

How can i test a directive that has a constant injected into them?
Here is my Below Code. Im also Getting **scope.element.node().getBoundingClientRect()** to be 0 0 0 0. Please help.

**Directive**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

angular.module('ng-visualization')
    .directive('ngMap', ngMap);

ngMap.$inject = ['worldTopo'];

function ngMap(topology) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            config: "=?"
        },
        compile: function (iElement, iAttrs) {
            console.log("Compiling..");
            return {
                pre: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    // console.log("Pre Linking..");
                    var uniqueId = "ng-map-" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
                    iElement.append('<div id=' + uniqueId + '></div>');
                    iElement.append('<div id=tooltip-' + uniqueId + '></div>');
                },
                post: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                    // console.log("Post Linking..");
                    $scope.element = d3.select(iElement.children()[0]);
                    $scope.tooltip = d3.select(iElement.children()[1]);
                    $scope.config = {
                        width: $scope.element.node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
                        height: $scope.element.node().getBoundingClientRect().width * 0.66,
                        land: {
                            fill: ($scope.config && $scope.config.land && $scope.config.land.fill) || "#B7B7B7",
                            hoverFill: ($scope.config && $scope.config.land && $scope.config.land.hoverFill) || "#008C95",
                            hoverText: ($scope.config && $scope.config.land && $scope.config.land.hoverText) || function (d) {
                                return d.properties.name;
                            },
                            clickToZoom: ($scope.config && $scope.config.land && $scope.config.land.clickToZoom) || true,
                            zoomTo: function (location, scale) {}
                        }
                    };

                    $scope.svg = $scope.element.append("svg").style({
                        display: "inline-block",
                        position: "relative",
                        width: $scope.config.width || "100%",
                        height: $scope.config.height || "100%",
                        // "padding-bottom": $scope.config.height || "100%",
                        "vertical-align": "middle",
                        overflow: "hidden"
                    });

                    $scope.globalG = $scope.svg.append("g");
                    $scope.mapG = $scope.globalG.append("g").attr("id", "map");

                    $scope.tooltip
                        .style({
                            "display": "inline-block",
                            "border-bottom": "1 px dotted black",
                            "visibility": "hidden",
                            "width": "200px",
                            "background-color": "white",
                            // "border": "19px",
                            "border": "1px solid #777777",
                            // "color": "#fff",
                            "text-align": "center",
                            // "border-radius": "6px",
                            "padding": "5px 5px",
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "z-index": "100"

                        })

                    $scope.projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                        .center([0, 0])
                        .scale($scope.config.width / 2 / Math.PI)
                        .translate([$scope.config.width / 2, $scope.config.height / 1.4])
                        .rotate([-10, 0]);

                    $scope.path = d3.geo.path()
                        .projection($scope.projection);

                    $scope.mapG.selectAll("path")
                        .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.countries).features)
                        .enter()
                        .append("path")
                        .attr("d", $scope.path)
                        .style("fill", $scope.config.land.fill)
                        .on("mouseover", function () {
                            $scope.tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
                            d3.select(this).style("fill", $scope.config.land.hoverFill);
                        })
                        .on("mousemove", function (d) {
                            $scope.tooltip.html($scope.config.land.hoverText(d));
                            $scope.tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
                        })
                        .on("mouseout", function () {
                            $scope.tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
                            d3.select(this).style("fill", $scope.config.land.fill);
                        })
                        .on("click", function (d) {
                            if ($scope.config.land.clickToZoom) {
                                var x, y, k;
                                if (d && $scope.centered !== d) {
                                    var centroid = $scope.path.centroid(d);
                                    x = centroid[0];
                                    y = centroid[1];
                                    k = 3;
                                    $scope.centered = d;
                                } else {
                                    x = $scope.config.width / 2;
                                    y = $scope.config.height / 2;
                                    k = 1;
                                    $scope.centered = null;
                                }
                                $scope.globalG.transition()
                                    .duration(750)
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + $scope.config.width / 2 + "," + $scope.config.height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
                                    .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
                            }
                        });

                }
            }
        }
    };
}

})();
```

**Test Case**

```
describe('ngMap', function () {

var $compile, $scope, topojson;

beforeEach(function () {
    module('ng-visualization');
    module(function ($provide) {
        // console.log($provide.constant)
        $provide.constant('worldTopo', {});
    })
    inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _worldTopo_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        topojson = _worldTopo_;
        console.log(_worldTopo_);
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    });
});

it('should Replaces the element with the appropriate content', function () {

    var element = angular.element("<ng-map></ng-map>");
    console.log(element);
    console.log(d3.select(element));
    console.log("B4 Compiling..");
    var directive = $compile(element)($scope);
    console.log("After Compiling..");
    var scope = element.isolateScope();
    console.log(scope.element.node().getBoundingClientRect());
    scope.$apply();

});
});
```

**Results**

```
ngBar
    √ should Replaces the element with the appropriate content
LOG LOG: Object{}
LOG LOG: Object{0: <ng-map></ng-map>, length: 1}
LOG LOG: [[Object{0: ..., length: ...}]]
LOG LOG: 'B4 Compiling..'
LOG LOG: 'Compiling..'

  ngMap
    × should Replaces the element with the appropriate content
        ReferenceError: **Can't find variable: topojson in src/js/ng-visualization.ng-map.directive.js (line 9)**
        post@src/js/ng-visualization.ng-map.directive.js:9:5855
        src/third_party/angular/angular.js:1346:23
        src/third_party/angular/angular.js:10420:49
        invokeLinkFn@src/third_party/angular/angular.js:10426:15
        nodeLinkFn@src/third_party/angular/angular.js:9815:23
        compositeLinkFn@src/third_party/angular/angular.js:9055:23
        publicLinkFn@src/third_party/angular/angular.js:8920:45
        test/ng-visualization.ng-map.directive.spec.js:25:42


PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.011 secs / 0.057 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 1 SUCCESS
```

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried renaming the `topology` variable `worldTopo`?

Comment: The error says it all. topojson var is not defined in directive function. You won't get valid  getBounding... because it's zero on detached elements. It's not unit test but functional test, and not a stable one. In unit test the proper strategy is to stub/mock everything. Consider testing real DOM in e2e